# BigQuery Error JSON_EXTRACT although jsonPath is valid

Tags: json, google-bigquery

I'm trying to extract some information out of the httparchive har tables, which are provided for free.
Trouble is that BQ returns an error on a `JSON_EXTRACT()` function although a number of jsonPath validators are executing it perfectly (http://jsonpath.com/ or jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/).
This is my query:

```
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(payload,"$._host")AS host,
  JSON_EXTRACT(payload,"$.request.headers[?(@.name=='Referer')]")AS referer,
  url,
  payload
FROM
  [httparchive:har.2016_01_01_chrome_requests]
LIMIT
  100
```

expected return based on the example payload json below would be

> "http://www.echosdunet.net/"

This is the error:

> Error: JSONPath parse error at: [?(@.name=='Referer')]

This is an example payload json:

```
{
    "pageref": "page_1_0",
    "startedDateTime": "2016-01-03T22:18:52.632+00:00",
    "time": 452,
    "request": {
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&version=f3e1717b71e7256da258d3a504e56865&f=echosdunet&t_i=node%2F19849&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.echosdunet.net%2Fnode%2F19849&t_e=Accueil&t_d=Comparatif%20et%20test%20ADSL%20et%20fibre&t_t=Accueil&s_o=default&l=fr",
        "headersSize": 650,
        "bodySize": -1,
        "cookies": [],
        "headers": [{
            "name": "Host",
            "value": "disqus.com"
        }, {
            "name": "Connection",
            "value": "keep-alive"
        }, {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
        }, {
            "name": "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
            "value": "1"
        }, {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36 PTST/254"
        }, {
            "name": "Referer",
            "value": "http://www.echosdunet.net/"
        }, {
            "name": "Accept-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip, deflate, sdch"
        }, {
            "name": "Accept-Language",
            "value": "en-US,en;q=0.8"
        }],
        "httpVersion": "1.1",
        "queryString": [{
            "name": "base",
            "value": "default"
        }, {
            "name": "version",
            "value": "f3e1717b71e7256da258d3a504e56865"
        }, {
            "name": "f",
            "value": "echosdunet"
        }, {
            "name": "t_i",
            "value": "node/19849"
        }, {
            "name": "t_u",
            "value": "http://www.echosdunet.net/node/19849"
        }, {
            "name": "t_e",
            "value": "Accueil"
        }, {
            "name": "t_d",
            "value": "Comparatif et test ADSL et fibre"
        }, {
            "name": "t_t",
            "value": "Accueil"
        }, {
            "name": "s_o",
            "value": "default"
        }, {
            "name": "l",
            "value": "fr"
        }]
    },
    "response": {
        "status": 200,
        "statusText": "",
        "headersSize": 1161,
        "bodySize": 2017,
        "headers": [{
            "name": "Server",
            "value": "nginx"
        }, {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
        }, {
            "name": "Content-Security-Policy",
            "value": "script-src https://*.twitter.com:* https://api.adsnative.com/v1/ad.json *.adsafeprotected.com https://cas.criteo.com/delivery/0.1/napi.jsonp *.services.disqus.com:* http://referrer.disqus.com/juggler/ disqus.com http://*.twitter.com:* a.disquscdn.com https://referrer.disqus.com/juggler/ https://*.services.disqus.com:* *.moatads.com 'unsafe-eval' https://mobile.adnxs.com/mob https://ssl.google-analytics.com"
        }, {
            "name": "Link",
            "value": "<http://a.disquscdn.com>;rel=preconnect,<http://a.disquscdn.com>;rel=dns-prefetch"
        }, {
            "name": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "stale-if-error=3600, s-stalewhilerevalidate=3600, stale-while-revalidate=30, no-cache, must-revalidate, public, s-maxage=5"
        }, {
            "name": "p3p",
            "value": "CP=\\DSP IDC CUR ADM DELi STP NAV COM UNI INT PHY DEM\\"
        }, {
            "name": "Timing-Allow-Origin",
            "value": "*"
        }, {
            "name": "X-Content-Type-Options",
            "value": "nosniff"
        }, {
            "name": "X-XSS-Protection",
            "value": "1; mode=block"
        }, {
            "name": "Last-Modified",
            "value": "Thu, 11 Jun 2015 13:30:36 GMT"
        }, {
            "name": "ETag",
            "value": "W/\\lounge:view:3840102421.d93d9c4bc037078ffc811833ae267a6f.0\\"
        }, {
            "name": "Content-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip"
        }, {
            "name": "Content-Length",
            "value": "2017"
        }, {
            "name": "Accept-Ranges",
            "value": "bytes"
        }, {
            "name": "Date",
            "value": "Sun, 03 Jan 2016 22:18:51 GMT"
        }, {
            "name": "Age",
            "value": "0"
        }, {
            "name": "Connection",
            "value": "keep-alive"
        }, {
            "name": "Vary",
            "value": "Accept-Encoding"
        }],
        "httpVersion": "1.1",
        "redirectURL": "",
        "content": {
            "size": 2017,
            "mimeType": "text/html"
        },
        "cookies": []
    },
    "cache": {},
    "timings": {
        "blocked": -1,
        "dns": 202,
        "connect": 32,
        "ssl": -1,
        "send": 0,
        "wait": 108,
        "receive": 110
    },
    "_ip_addr": "104.156.81.134",
    "_method": "GET",
    "_host": "disqus.com",
    "_url": "/embed/comments/?base=default&version=f3e1717b71e7256da258d3a504e56865&f=echosdunet&t_i=node%2F19849&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.echosdunet.net%2Fnode%2F19849&t_e=Accueil&t_d=Comparatif%20et%20test%20ADSL%20et%20fibre&t_t=Accueil&s_o=default&l=fr",
    "_responseCode": "200",
    "_load_ms": "218",
    "_ttfb_ms": "108",
    "_load_start": "2632",
    "_bytesOut": "652",
    "_bytesIn": "3180",
    "_objectSize": "2017",
    "_cacheControl": "stale-if-error=3600, s-stalewhilerevalidate=3600, stale-while-revalidate=30, no-cache, must-revalidate, public, s-maxage=5",
    "_contentType": "text/html",
    "_contentEncoding": "gzip",
    "_type": "3",
    "_socket": "153",
    "_score_cache": "-1",
    "_score_cdn": "-1",
    "_score_gzip": "100",
    "_score_cookies": "-1",
    "_score_keep-alive": "100",
    "_score_minify": "-1",
    "_score_combine": "-1",
    "_score_compress": "-1",
    "_score_etags": "-1",
    "_is_secure": "0",
    "_dns_ms": 202,
    "_connect_ms": 32,
    "_ssl_ms": "-1",
    "_gzip_total": "3180",
    "_gzip_save": "0",
    "_minify_total": "0",
    "_minify_save": "0",
    "_image_total": "0",
    "_image_save": "0",
    "_cache_time": "-1",
    "_dns_start": "2395",
    "_dns_end": "2597",
    "_connect_start": "2600",
    "_connect_end": "2632",
    "_ssl_start": "0",
    "_ssl_end": "0",
    "_initiator": "http://echosdunet.disqus.com/embed.js?_=1451859532217",
    "_initiator_line": "16",
    "_initiator_column": "8205",
    "_server_count": "4",
    "_server_rtt": "32",
    "_client_port": "62284",
    "_jpeg_scan_count": "0",
    "_full_url": "http://disqus.com/embed/comments/?base=default&version=f3e1717b71e7256da258d3a504e56865&f=echosdunet&t_i=node%2F19849&t_u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.echosdunet.net%2Fnode%2F19849&t_e=Accueil&t_d=Comparatif%20et%20test%20ADSL%20et%20fibre&t_t=Accueil&s_o=default&l=fr",
    "_score_progressive_jpeg": -1,
    "_body": true,
    "_load_end": 2850,
    "_ttfb_start": "2632",
    "_ttfb_end": 2740,
    "_download_start": 2740,
    "_download_end": 2850,
    "_download_ms": 110,
    "_all_start": "2395",
    "_all_end": 2850,
    "_all_ms": 452,
    "_index": 55,
    "_number": 56,
    "_body_url": "/response_body.php?test=160101_10_KZQ1&run=1&cached=0&request=56"
}
```

Running the query without the referer jsonPath works fine:

```
SELECT
      JSON_EXTRACT(payload,"$._host")AS host,
      url,
      payload
    FROM
      [httparchive:har.2016_01_01_chrome_requests]
    LIMIT
      100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meantime, try below (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(json STRING, key String)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE js AS """
  try { 
    var parsed = JSON.parse(json);
    for (i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) { 
      if (parsed[i].name == key) return parsed[i].value
    }  
  } catch (e) {}
  return null;
""";
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT(payload,"$._host")AS host,
  CUSTOM_JSON_EXTRACT(JSON_EXTRACT(payload, "$.request.headers"), 'Referer') AS referer,
  url,
  payload
FROM
  `httparchive.har.2016_01_01_chrome_requests`
LIMIT
  100
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot. I guess my queries will have to look a lot more complex with this kind of workaround in the future though :)

Answer (score 1):

`JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR` do not support the complete set of JSONPath elements. You can read more in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#json-functions). I would suggest using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) since that implementation of the JSON functions has better error messages.

If you are interested in additional kinds of JSONPath elements, you can consider [submitting a feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0).